# Moving cells to last row without erasing over existing

Tags: excel, vba

The following code checks to see if any of my rows on the main page contain a date from a year ago or older. If it does, it copies it to the "Archive" worksheet and deletes it from the main page. However, what it's doing now is just copying from the main page and overriding what already exists on the archive page instead of adding to the last row. I've tried subbing in LastRow from a function, but I was getting an error with how I was using it. Anyone have a better solution?

```
Sub TestDateTransfer()
With Application
PrevCalc = .Calculation
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.Cursor = xlWait
.Calculate
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Archive").Activate
Range("A3:I1000").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Worksheets("Main Page").Activate
Dim MyDate As Date
MyDate = "03/27/2017"
Set i = Sheets("Main Page")
Set E = Sheets("Archive")
Dim d
Dim j
d = 2
j = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("C" & j))

  If i.Range("C" & j) <= MyDate - 365 Then
  d = d + 1
  E.rows(d).Value = i.rows(j).Value

  End If
  j = j + 1
 Loop
 Worksheets("Archive").Activate
 ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Select 'To unselect the page
 Worksheets("Main Page").Activate
 MyDate = "03/27/2017"
 Dim y
 Dim z
 y = 2
 z = 2
 Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("C" & z))

  If i.Range("C" & z) <= MyDate - 365 Then
  y = y + 1
  i.rows(z).Delete

  End If
  z = z + 1
  Loop
 With Application
.Cursor = xlDefault
.Calculate
.Calculation = PrevCalc
'.ScreenUpdating = True 'Not Needed...
.EnableEvents = True
 End With
 ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Select
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Worksheets("Archive").Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "hai"
```

I have written a small piece of code that shows you how to use this. My code is different than yours b/c it loops through the range and checks each cell if the value of the difference between it and NOW is greater than or equal to 1 (which is how to tell if its from lats year or not). Its not how you approach it but it does seem to be more simplified in the approach. Alsoe I soted a bucnh of dates in a spreadsheet and tested this out. just apply to your needs. I hope this helps more?

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rcell As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20")

    For Each rcell In rng.Cells
        'note that if you dont put a handler in here to deal with blank cells values this code will run forever. most peop-le do a check with "if rcell.valeu <> vbNullString then etc etc
        If DateDiff("yyyy", rcell.Value, Now()) >= 1 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = rcell.Value
            rcell.Value = vbNullString
        End If
    Next rcell
End Sub
```

Comment: Sheet1 would need to be what sheet # it is :)

Comment: Hm, how exactly do you suggest I plug this in? In please of E.rows(d).Value?

Comment: I subbed it in there and now it only replaces column A and still gets overwritten/overwrites O.O

Comment: @dwirony i have edited my answer to help show you some application

Answer (score 0):

You could exploit `AutoFilter()` method of `Range` object and copy/paste filtered rows in one shot:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim MyDate As Date
    MyDate = "03/27/2017"

    Dim E As Worksheet
    Set E = Worksheets("Archive")

    With Worksheets("Main Page")
        With .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<=" & CDbl((MyDate - 365))
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow).Copy Destination:=E.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```